# SQL: Removing entire group when case is something in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by

I am using postgreSQL, I have two tables, one is user, and one is usertasks.

user has following fields : **userid, username**

usertasks has following fields: **taskid, taskdate, userid**

userid and id are primary keys on above tables

I want to find all users who have not made any tasks between two specific dates.

My query is this:

```
Select u.userid
from users u
left join usertasks ut
on ut.userid=u.userid
group by u.userid
having count(case when ut.task_date >= '2015-7-1' AND ut.task_date <= '2015-10-6' then null else 1 end)>=1
```

**Problem:**
Some users have done tasks between those dates and have also done tasks excluding those two dates, so those users are returned as well, I don't want those users, because they have done tasks between those dates, I am interested only those users who have not done any tasks between those two dates.
It would work if entire group can be skipped if any of the tasks in that group are done between those two dates.

So basically, I want a query equivalent to this:

```
(Select u.userid
from users u)
except
(Select u.userid
from users u
left join usertasks ut
on ut.userid=u.userid
where ut.task_date >= '2015-7-1' AND ut.task_date <= '2015-10-6'
group by u.userid)
```

The above query returns right result, but its slower, thats why I can't use except or NOT IN.

**SAMPLE DATA:**
Create tables:

```
create table users( userid serial PRIMARY KEY, username VARCHAR(20) );


create table usertasks(taskid serial PRIMARY KEY,  userid BIGINT, taskdate DATE );
```

Insert data:

```
INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES 
('a'),
('b'),
('c'),
('d'),
('e'),
('f');
INSERT INTO usertasks (userid,taskdate) VALUES 
(1,'2015-11-5'),
(1,'2015-10-1'),
(2,'2015-9-2'),
(3,'2015-9-2'),
(4,'2015-9-2'),
(5,'2015-9-2'),
(6,'2015-11-2');
```

according to the query, none of the usertasks with userid 1 should return

Comment: Prepare http://sqlfiddle.com  with sample data. Your question is unclear for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to user `not exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from usertasks ut
                  where ut.userid = u.userid and
                        ut.task_date >= '2015-07-01' and
                        ut.booking_date <= '2015-10-06'
                 );
```

This seems like a direct translation of your requirement.

That said, this query:

```
Select u.userid
from users u left join
     usertasks ut
     on ut.userid = u.userid
group by u.userid
having sum(case when ut.task_date >= '2015-7-1' AND ut.booking_date <= '2015-10-6' then 1 end) = 0;
```

Should return the same result.  I think the problem with your query is the `having` clause:

```
having count(case when ut.task_date >= '2015-7-1' AND ut.booking_date <= '2015-10-6' then null else 1 end) >= 1
```

Because of the `left join`, users with no tasks will end up with a count value of 1.  Why?  Because the `ut` fields will be `NULL`, which fails the comparison.  Hence the `else` clause is used.  The `SUM()` version doesn't have this short-coming.

Comment: thanks for giving the idea, it worked with count = 0 as well... >=1 was the problem..